# AngularJS: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined $http

Tags: angularjs, http, undefined

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('Controller', function($scope, $interval){

    $interval(function($scope, $http){

        $http.get('test.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.notifications = data;
        });
    },5000);

});
```

Anyone See what exactly I'm doing wrong? The interval is working correctly, as the error repeats ever 5 seconds in Chrome's Console. Am I passing the $http correctly to the controller?

Comment: you don't appear to be passing `$http` into the controller at all....

Comment: create a factory and have a method to do the http get and invoke that method over here, after injecting the factory in the controller. as @Claies mentioned in this example you forgot to inject $http

Answer (score 1):

All Angular module should be injected in the constructor of the controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('Controller', function($http, $scope, $interval){

$interval(function(){
    $http.get('test.json').success(function(data){
          $scope.notifications = data;
    });
},5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $http into your controller.  (The same way you inject $scope and $interval.)  You may be interested to read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('Controller', function($scope, $interval, $http){

    $interval(function($scope, $http){

        $http.get('test.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.notifications = data;
        });
    },5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you injected the `$interval` service, you need to inject the `$http` service:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('Controller', function($scope, $interval, $http){

    $interval(function($scope, $http){

        $http.get('test.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.notifications = data;
        });
    },5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass in $http in your controller, as:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).
myApp.controller('ImagesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
    $interval(function(){

        $http.get('test.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.notifications = data;
        });
    },5000);
}]);
```